# What shall I write for a reason for applying graduate school for algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

I'm a undergraduate applying a graduate school this year and now I'm writing a letter of self-introduction.

To be honest, I don't know what exactly is algebraic geometry and I think 99% of undergraduates don't know what it is **in general** since it requires so many preliminaries.

I'm applying for algebraic geometry, since I know that this is a very deep and intrinsic subject which is itself important and its technique can be used to prove other parts of mathematics. For an example, Fermat's last theorem was proven by algebraic geometry method.

Moreover, I want to feel and touch Grothendieck's arguments and ideas so that I can really say how great he it.

But, that is it and I think professors won't see this nice.

Please help me what should I write for the reason applying for algebraic geometry.. This question sounds stupid, but it is really what I have in my mind now and I really want to get to study algebraic geometry..

Comment: This may be a question better suited for mathematics-educators or academia.....not sure though

Comment: You write "I think professors won't see this nice". Speaking for myself, I am a professor and an algebraic geometer and I like your reasons. Of course I cannot know how others would react, but I think that being candid about your motivation is a good strategy.

Comment: If you feel you don't know what it is then why do you wish to study it? (Also I am not sure about your statement about FLT, yes certain tools from AG were used but so were many other tools!).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you! Could you tell me when were you impressed while reading applicants introduction? I'm really desperate..

Comment: @fretty Yes, I know that it sounds nonsense, but it is really what I feel. The reason why I changed my major to mathematics (i majored physics before) is to study algebraic geometry.. I was so impressed that Grothendieck generalized many theorems and paved golden roads.

Comment: I'd say try to be more concrete.  How did he "pave golden roads?"  Which theorems?  At the same time, don't BS -- whoever reads your application will know his/her stuff, and will see through it.  Be honest.  Don't worry so much about whether people will be impressed.

Comment: Dear Rubertos, in the French system students don't write letters of self -introduction so I can't say "what impressed me" in such letters. I advise you to be frank, as you are here, instead of having others giving you explanations on why algebraic geometry is great (which it is :-)): as I said your motivation is quite acceptable. Also browse §8 of Miles Reid's [book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KvKdSkPwwmMC&hl=fr), where the sociological explanations are both profound and very witty, in the best of British traditions.

Comment: @user148177 I'm sorry that I misunderstood your comment.. I didn't read the first line. Sorry just ignore my comments.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome, Rubertos: lovers of algebraic geometry should stick together :-)

Comment: Being a rather deep, demmanding subject, algebraic geometry requires a rather hefty background in several subjects, like algebra (commutative and non-commutative), complex analysis, topology and etc. It will probably be wise to add that you have a good knowledge in these subjects *or else* that you're more than willing to complete your education in them.  Wishing to know something is far from being enough to actually getting at once to know it. Sometimes it requires long, deep preparation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some personal thoughts (speaking as an algebraic geometer, and someone who reads such statements.) I hope they are helpful.

1. As user148177 says, "don't BS". (In case it is not clear to non-native speakers of English, "BS" is an abbreviation for "bullshit", meaning to pretend to know more than you do.) Nobody expects you to know much about algebraic geometry, much less know what is in "in general", or to know all the preliminaries. If that standard was applied to applicants, nobody would ever start a PhD (in any subject)! Don't try to impress anyone with fancy notions; be honest! (I recently read an application that had a long "research statement" full of fancy notions; it was immediately evident that it had been copied from the internet.)
2. You say you want "to feel and touch Grothendieck's arguments and ideas so that I can really say how great he i[s]." I understand this motivation, but some readers might not appreciate the sentiment so much. It might sound like you are too fixated on the work of one (albeit great) individual: for instance, what will you do if your advisor wants you to work on something not so close to Grothendieck's kind of algebraic geometry? Will you be flexible and adapt, or run away to the library and bury your head in EGA for three years? It's good to talk about your admiration for Grothendieck, but remember that doing a PhD isn't just about learning from the greats: you have to make *your own* contribution. Your letter should show that you understand that, even if you don't know what that contribution will be.
3. Again echoing user148177, I advise you to try to say *something* specific and concrete that appeals to you about algebraic geometry. Have you looked at the introductory textbooks, like Reid and Shafarevich? Was there a topic or result in there that you liked, even if you didn't understand it fully? Talk about that, in a straightforward way. If your letter shows that you have no clear idea about the basic ideas and techniques of algebraic geometry, a potential advisor will (justifiably) wonder what is going to happen when you have to start learning these. Put another way, you have to demonstrate that you really do have some enthusiasm for algebraic geometry (even if you don't know much), rather than the **idea** of algebraic geometry.

Let me finish by saying that your passion is a great asset to you, and I don't mean to dampen it at all. If you can convey the same passion while addressing the points here and in the comments, your letter will be in great shape.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful! :))